# Strange behaviour on text color in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose-text

Hey I am new in jetpack compose. I tried to set window background color black and white according to theme. When I created custom theme and set background color my text color will be black.

**theme.kt**

```
package com.vivek.sportsresult.ui.theme

import android.os.Build
import androidx.compose.foundation.isSystemInDarkTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import com.google.accompanist.systemuicontroller.rememberSystemUiController

private val DarkColorScheme = darkColorScheme(
    primary = Purple80,
    secondary = PurpleGrey80,
    tertiary = Pink80,
    background = Color.Black
)

private val LightColorScheme = lightColorScheme(
    primary = Purple40,
    secondary = PurpleGrey40,
    tertiary = Pink40,
    background = Color.White
)

@Composable
fun SportsResultTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isDarkTheme(),
    // Dynamic color is available on Android 12+
    dynamicColor: Boolean = true,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()
    val colorScheme = when {
        dynamicColor && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S -> {
            val context = LocalContext.current
            if (darkTheme) dynamicDarkColorScheme(context) else dynamicLightColorScheme(context)
        }
        darkTheme -> {
            DarkColorScheme
        }
        else -> {
            LightColorScheme
        }
    }

    if (darkTheme) {
        systemUiController.setSystemBarsColor(
            color = Color.Black
        )
    } else {
        systemUiController.setSystemBarsColor(
            color = Color.White
        )
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = colorScheme,
        typography = Typography,
        content = content
    )
}

@Composable
fun isDarkTheme() = isSystemInDarkTheme()

@Composable
fun getBackgroundColor() = if (isDarkTheme()) {
    DarkColorScheme.background
} else {
    LightColorScheme.background
}
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.vivek.sportsresult

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.vivek.sportsresult.ui.theme.SportsResultTheme
import com.vivek.sportsresult.ui.theme.getBackgroundColor

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            SportsResultTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = getBackgroundColor()
                ) {
                    Log.e("TAG", "onCreate: ")
                    Greeting("Android")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String) {
    Text(text = "Hello $name!")
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    SportsResultTheme {
        Greeting("Android")
    }
}
```

When I tried to use `color = getBackgroundColor()` it not changing text color but if use `color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background` it working correct on dark and white theme. I don't understand why? Can someone guide me on this?

**Actual Output**

[image]

**Expected Output**

[image]

Comment: Are you running this on a device that has Android 12 or on a device that has 11 or lower version?

Comment: My emulator is android 12. I didn't check in older device yet.

Comment: @Ma3x any update on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background` it works correctly because in that case the `Surface` composable is able to determine the correct content color (that would be the `contentColor` parameter) based on the background color which you set (which is the `color` parameter).

However, when you use `getBackgroundColor()` in dark mode you get back `Color.Black` and since you are running your code on a device with Android 12 your theme is a dynamic color theme which was created here

```
    val colorScheme = when {
        dynamicColor && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S -> {
            val context = LocalContext.current
            if (darkTheme) dynamicDarkColorScheme(context) else dynamicLightColorScheme(context)
        }
```

and apparently does not contain any color that is exactly `Color.Black`, i.e. that is exactly `Color(0xFF000000)`, and thus the `Surface` composable is *unable* to determine the correct content color.

When a given color is not found in the theme then the `contentColor` is set to `LocalContentColor.current` and it just happens that in your case this results in a black text on a black background.

You have 2 options:

1. you can use `MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background` and let it determine the `contentColor` automatically based on your theme.
2. you can set both `color` and `contentColor` yourself like this

```
Surface(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    color = getBackgroundColor(),
    contentColor = /* get and set some content color */, 
)
```

This behavior is due to how `Surface` `contentColor` parameter default value is implemented by calling `contentColorFor(color)`. See the Surface composable implementation and `contentColorFor` implementation (in Android Studio you Ctrl/Cmd+click on them, or open the context menu > Go To > Implementation).